# Python turtle problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

The website doesnt explain things well
A solution would be much appreactiated
This is the question:

Write a function to draw a rectangle of any size and colour. We will use this function to make some art!

We've started your function already; it's called draw_rect. It takes these arguments:

width — number of turtle steps

height — number of turtle steps

colour — the pencolor to use

Your function should draw a rectangle with the bottom-left corner at the starting position. Use a pen with the correct colour, and set the size to 3.

If we call your function like this:

```
draw_rect(110, 30, 'cornflowerblue')
```

Then your function should draw:

We've provided a function that calls draw_rect for you, so you can test your function.

This is my code:

```
from turtle import *

def draw_rect(width, height, colour):
  # Draw a rectangle with code!
  #help needed here!
  pencolor('cornflowerblue')
  pensize(3)
  forward(110)
  left(90)
  forward(30)
  left(90)
  forward(110)
  left(90)
  forward(30)
  left(90)

def draw_city():
  draw_rect(30, 120, 'royalblue')
  goto(-10, 0)
  draw_rect(80, 30, 'cornflowerblue')
  goto(-30, 0)
  draw_rect(80, 60, 'coral')
  goto(-45, 0)
  draw_rect(50, 80, 'plum')
  goto(-55, 0)
  draw_rect(90, 15, 'orange')
  goto(-75, 0)
  draw_rect(20, 40, 'pink')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Test your code here!
  draw_rect(110, 40, 'green')

  # Uncomment this to draw a city:
  #draw_city()
```

I'm honestly stuck and to reiterate an answer would be much appreactiated

Comment: Do not worry about the def draw_city

Comment: NVM i got it guys thanks for the help